# What makes non linear functions computationally expensive in hardware (e.g. FPGA)?

Tags: hardware, fpga

I've read some articles that state non-linear functions (like exponentials) are computationally expensive.

I was wondering what makes them computationally expensive.

When referring to 'computationally expensive' does it mean in terms of time taken or hardware resources used?

I've tried searching on Google, but I couldn't find any simple explanations for this.

Answer (score 2):

Not pretending to offer *the answer*, but start with what you have in fpga.

Normally you're limited to adders, multipliers and some memory. What can you do with those?

Linear function - easy, taking just one multiplier and one adder.

Nonlinear functions - what a those? Either polynomial, requiring you to spend a ton of multipliers (the more the higher the polynomial's degree), or even transcendental, requiring you to find some satisfactory approximation, doing that in many steps.
Even simple integer division can't be done in one clock, in simple implementations requiring as many steps as there's bits in the numbers being divided.

The other possible solution is to use a lookup tables. And it's great for a small range of arguments. But if you want to have the function values found in wide range of arguments, or with greater precision, you'll end up with lookup table that is so large that can't fit in the device you have to work with.

So that's the main costs - you'll spend lots of dedicated hardware resources (multipliers, memory for lookup tables), or spend lots of time in many-steps approximation algorithms, or algorithms that refine the results one "digit" per iteration (integer division, CORDIC, etc).